# How can i get results from an association table created with a ManyToMany relation with Hibernate Jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am really new with hibernate sorry for any basic error So i have 2 entities User and Establishment, and i have mapped those entities with a ManyToMany relationship using hibernate like so:

User.java entity:

```
   @Entity
   @Table
   public class User extend AbstractEntity {

   @Column(name = "name", length = 255, nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "email", length = 120)
   private String email;

   @Column(name = "phone")
   private String phone;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name= "User_Establishment",
   joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id") },
   inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="establishment_id") })
   private List<Establishment> establishments;


   public List<Establishment> getEstablishments() {
         return establishments;
   }

   public void setEstablishment(List<Establishment> establishments) {
         this.establishments= establishments;
   }
   }
```

and Establishment.java entity:

```
   @Entity
   @Table
   public class Establishment extend AbstractEntity{

     @Column(name="nif", nullable=false, length=10)
     private String nif;

     @Column(name="code", nullable=false, length=11)
     private String code;

     @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
     private String name;

     @Column(name="address")
     private String address;

     @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "establishments")
     private List<User> users;

     public List<User> getUser() {
           return users;
     }

     public void setUser(List<User> users) {
           this.users= users;
     }

   }
```

both entities have an Id, its just not there because im extending an Abstract class that has those values.

And it created a table in the database named User_Establishment like so:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      user_id        | establishment_id |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

so far so good, i can add values in the table properly using the seters and geters.
But now i want to get those values using a query with hibernate, but i dont really know how to do it, because when i try to create a query to access that data in a Repository, i cant because i dont have a Repository for the association table.

So giving the user_id as parameter, i want every establishment_id, in order to get everything from the establishment Table, giving the establishment_id

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to query for, can you elaborate a little?

Comment: ok sorry i will elaborate, So giving the user_id as parameter, i want every establishment_id, in order to get everything from the establishment Table, giving the establishment_id

Comment: You should select the user by userId, then you will have all the establishments as a collection through the getEstablishments getter, as suggested by @LunaticJape below.

Answer (score 1):

Repository usually is just a place to put persistence-related logic and there is no need to create one unless you imply something else.

Every time you query an User or an Establishment you can navigate the corresponding association and grab the data you need as this:

```
User user = entityManager.find(User.class, "SOMENAME");
user.getEstablishments(); // should give the related values`
```

Comment: I see... but that "SOMENAME" can be a value from the association table?

Comment: @coderTester No, for that you need a criteria (ou criterion in jpa2) or an JQL query

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to get all establishments of a user, it's very simple using Spring Data JPA.

```
User user = userDao.findById(userId);
List<Establishment> establishments = user.getEstablishments();
```

The above code should be enough.